# How to resolve the deprecation of format option in @CucumberOptions?

Tags: java, cucumber

When i am using the option *format* in `@CucumberOptions` for test reports it is showing that the format option has been deprecated how to resolve that.

```
@CucumberOptions( monochrome = true, format = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber-json-report.json" })
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

replace **format** with **plugin**

`@CucumberOptions( monochrome = true,plugin = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber-json-report.json" })`