# How to resolve deprecated @CucumberOptions?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

In the following code i was using @cucumber.options.But it says it is deprecated.

So i am trying to use @cucumberoptions which requires an import of "cucumber.api.CucumberOptions".
But when i checked in my maven dependencies , cucumber.api does not contain cucumberoptions.
And i am getting a red line for my import "import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;"

My aim is to create a good report and set its path .

I could find a related question - [How to resolve the deprecation of format option in @CucumberOptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138086/how-to-resolve-the-deprecation-of-format-option-in-cucumberoptions) here but could not find an answer i am looking for.
I would really appreciate if any of you could find a resolution to this .

My Code is as follows:-

```
package featurefiles;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.*;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = false, features = "features", format = { "pretty",
    "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty",
    "json:target/cucumber.json" }, tags = { "~@ignore" })
public class CucumberTestRunner {
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Instead of :

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
```

Use:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the legacy classes import them from io package:

`import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;` >> `import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;`
and
`import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber` >> `import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;`

Answer (score 2):

I found answer to this .

```
{import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;}
```

was not needed .

Thanks.

Comment: SO do you mean `@CucumberOptions` is not required?